# Calling Cross domain WCF Service Using jQuery AJAX with JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, wcf

I am new with WCF and almost try every Web Site to do this task. This Is My Service

```
namespace WCFSeviceWebHttpBinding
{
 "IService1" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]

public interface IService1
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json , UriTemplate="/d")]
    [OperationContract]
    string DoWork();
}
}

namespace WCFSeviceWebHttpBinding
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{

    public string DoWork()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
}
```

Web.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFSeviceWebHttpBinding.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviour">
        <!--<endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBinding" contract="WCFSeviceWebHttpBinding.IService1"/>-->
        <endpoint address="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicWebBinding" contract="WCFSeviceWebHttpBinding.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webhttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None"/>
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicWebBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None"/>
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webScriptEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" name=""></standardEndpoint>
      </webScriptEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"  />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <!--<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*"/>-->
        <!--<add name ="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*"/>-->
        <!--<add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000"/>-->
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

I am stuck to call this service using jquery ajax with json also try jsonp, Here is my aspx page.
I am almost try all web sites and procedure.

```
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#tbDetails').hide();


//        $('#btnClick').click(function () {
//            $.getJSON('http://localhost:34864/Service1.svc/d', function (json) {
//                //get information about the user usejquery from twitter api
//                $('#txtName').text(json);
//                //get the follower_count from the json object and put it in a span
//            });
           // - See more at: http://usejquery.com/blog/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide#sthash.56ebENSb.dpuf
       // });
                $('#btnClick').click(function () {
                    alert($("#txtName").val());
                    $.ajax({

                        type: "GET",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "http://localhost:34864/Service1.svc/d",
                        //method : 'DoWork',
                         crossDomain: true,
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        success: function (data) {

                            alert(data);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert(result);
                        }
                    });

                });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved
My serive

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace WCFSeviceWebHttpBinding
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]

    public interface IService1
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json )]
        [OperationContract]
        string DoWork();
    }
}
```

My service implementation

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace WCFSeviceWebHttpBinding
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        public string DoWork()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

Most importatnt my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true. Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NoSecurity">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFSeviceWebHttpBinding.Service1">
        <endpoint address="bh" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFSeviceWebHttpBinding.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="wh" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSeviceWebHttpBinding.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="rh" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"  contract="WCFSeviceWebHttpBinding.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"/>
        <endpoint address="jh" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NoSecurity" contract="WCFSeviceWebHttpBinding.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and now my client is web form hosted in another domain

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#Button1").click(function () {
                 var url = "http://localhost:34864/Service1.svc/rh/DoWork";
                 $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", { value: null }, function (data) {
                     alert(data);
                 });
             });
         });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my client side web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService11" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" />
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService11">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>

      <endpoint address="http://localhost:34864/Service1.svc/bh" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService11" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService11" />
      <!--<endpoint address="http://localhost:34864/Service1.svc/wh" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="SUNIL\IMPOSE" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:34864/Service1.svc/jh" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService11" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="WSHttpBinding_IService11" />-->
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```